# Find Volume of Solids

Tags: calculus, volume, rotations, solid-of-revolution

Let $f$($x$)= cos($x$) and $g$($x$)= 1-${\frac{x^2}{2}} \\$. Let $D$ be the region bounded by the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis between $x$= -${\frac{π}{2}} \\$ and $x$= ${\frac{π}{2}} \\$ and let $A$ be the region bounded by the graph $g$ and the $x$-axis.
$$\\$$

a) Use the Shells Method to find the volume of the solids generated by rotating $D$ and $A$ around the $y$-axis.

b) Compare your 2 results from part a, and explain graphically which one must be larger.

c) Use this comparison to prove something you already knew about $π$.
$$\\$$
This is what I have so far:

Region D:

$$2π\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x(1-{\frac{x^2}{2}}+cosx)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry, we only need to consider the branch from $0$ to $\displaystyle \sqrt{2}$, so we have $\displaystyle 2π\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}x\left|1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right|\,dx=π=\boxed{3.141}$ for the A solid.

Similarly, we have $\displaystyle 2π \int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}x\left|\cos(x)\right|\,dx=π^2-2π=\boxed{3.5864}$  for the D solid.

This is consistent with what we see, because $\cos(x)$ is more than $\displaystyle 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ on the interval.

So the cylindrical *shells* we obtain by rotating will be taller in the D solid than the A solid.

Not sure what this could prove about $π$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For region A, wouldn't the limits be [0,√2]? Because the graph of g(x) intersects x-axis at points (−√2,0) and (√2,0).

Comment: oh! my bad. did not see that.

Comment: wait, am I right? I originally put π/2 but someone told me it was √2...idk

Comment: no, you're right, you're right! but the D solid will use π/2 because its cos

Comment: What does the x represent? I was thinking it's the thickness of segment in the shaded regions

Comment: the x is the radius of the cylinder

Comment: f(x) is the height of the cylinder

Comment: dx is the thickness of the cylinder

Comment: The cross section would be perpendicular to the y-axis?

Comment: well, we arent' using cross sections here. we are using concentric cylinders

Comment: or shells, that is

Comment: what I meant was when you graph region D and shade it in, how is the shell drawn?

Comment: is it perpendicular to the y-axis or the x-axis?

Comment: uhhh perpendicular to the y-axis? because the cylinder is parallel to the y axis

Comment: ill draw it bro